# iframed site accessing frames outside of its own

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Background:
I am trying to iframe an entire external website for a project.  Some links within this external site are within even more frames.  They use js to access the top window and set its location according to the href value of the link, which results in the new page loading completely outside of my iframe (which I would like to avoid).

Question:
Has anyone dealt with this/is there a way to deal with this?  Ideally I would like to prevent the iframed site from accessing frames outside of its own.

Note:
As per my knowledge it is not possible but still want to have a second opinion

Thank you very much for any help or insight,

Comment: If the iframe's content is from a different domain than the domain of it's parent, it shouldn't be able to access the parent. It can however detect that it is within an iframe(google iframe killers).

Comment: you cannot modify the behaviour of the i *framed* site

Answer (score 0):

To get around the restriction for the iFrame sources, the only way you can do it by setting up a web proxy script on your website.

```
<iframe src="proxy.php?url=http://othersite.com/">
```

you should be able to find some proxy implementation on some script site.